# Norms of elements in a quadratic order - can you do it elementarily?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $\mathcal O$ be an order in an imaginary quadratic field $K$.

1. Does there exists an element $\lambda\in \mathcal O$ such that the norm $N(\lambda)$ is not a square?
2. Does there exists an element $\lambda\in \mathcal O$ such that the norm $N(\lambda)$ is squarefree and not equal to $1$?
3. **Is there an elementary solution for 1. and 2.?**

Note that if there was a simple proof of the first statement, then we could perhaps simplify the proof of the integrality of the $j$-invariant at $CM$ points by avoiding reduction to the case of the maximal order.

Comment: Part 1 is easy; e.g. if the order contains $\sqrt{-D}$ then $n+\sqrt{-D}$
has norm $n^2+D$, which is not a square once $2n+1>D$.  Part 2 is too easy
as stated because you can take $\lambda = 1$, so I guess you meant to impose
some additional constraint.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, Does every order contain a number of the form $\sqrt{-D}$?

Comment: Yes; for instance, the full ring of integers $O_K$ contains some $\sqrt{-D_0}$,
and $\cal O$ is contained in $O_K$ with finite index, say index $m$,
so $\cal O$ contains $m \sqrt{-D_0}$, and we may take $D = m^2 D_0$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes to both questions.

Let $C$ be the class group of the order $\mathcal{O}$. Then there exists infinitely many prime ideals of degree $1$ in $K$, invertible in $\mathcal{O}$, that represent the trivial class in $C$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is such a prime ideal, then its norm is a prime integer $p$, and there exists $\lambda\in\mathcal{O}$ such that $\lambda\mathcal{O}=\mathfrak{p}$: in particular $N(\lambda)=p$.

Comment: Is there a more elementary proof?